# PHPSpreadsheet load CSV float losing precision

Tags: phpspreadsheet

When loading a CSV with PHPSpreadsheet I am losing float precision.  Seems to be a maximum precision of 13.  Is this a PHPSpreadheet issue or PHP issue?

The cell value 4.020203251424**09** is loaded as 4.0202032514241 (13th character rounded up)

The cell value 3.908120053825**48** is loaded as 3.9081200538255 (13th character rounded up)

The cell value 4.556057651127**64** i s loaded as 4.5560576511276 (13th character same)

The cell value 4.473037893922**9**  is loaded as 4.4730378939229 (Only 13 characters)

Answer (score 0):

By referring to PHP [float point numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) documentation, I think it should be the PHP issue rather than PhpSpreadsheet.

> The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of
> approximately 1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is
> a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).

Not sure about your usage on those float number but a warm reminder from doc stated that :

> **Warning**
> ...
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit,
> and do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If
> higher precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions
> and gmp functions are available.
> ...